# Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::resource does not exist. In Macroable.php line 78

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to see the help of `php artisan make:controller --help` method but I get this error:

> In Macroable.php line 78:
>   Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::resource does not exist.

Comment: Can you create a controller?

Comment: what do your routes look like?(web.php, api.php) any namespaces in there?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I just needed to import this: 
````use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;````

I don't know why it wasn't there when I created the project. Btw I'm using Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I just needed to import this: 
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`

I don't know why it wasn't there when I created the project. Btw I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: If your mean is to import it in route.php, it dosent need to import or use Route. I have same problem because i make a mistake and import `use illuminate\Routing\Route` was my problem. i just remove it